# Find the lowest non-masked point with numpy efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The application here is finding the "cloud base", but the principles apply wherever. I have a numpy masked 3-D array (which we will say corresponds to a 3-D grid box with dimensions z, y, x), where I have masked out all points with a value of less than 0.1. What I want to find is, at every x,y point, what is the lowest z point index (not the lowest value in z, the smallest z coordinate) that is not masked out. I can think of a few trivial ways to do it, e.g.:

```
for x points:
    for y points:
        minz=-1
        for z points:
            if x,y,z is not masked:
                 minz = z 
                 break
```

However, this seems really inefficient and I'm sure that there is a more efficient or more pythonic way to do this. What am I missing here?

**Edit:** I do not *need* to use masked arrays, but it seemed like the easiest way to ask the question- I can instead find the lowest point under a certain threshold without using masked arrays.

**Edit 2:** Idea for what I'm looking for (taking z=0 to be the lowest point):

```
input:
[[[0,1],
  [1,5]],

 [[3,3],
  [2,4]],

 [[2,1],
  [4,9]]]

threshold: val >=3
output:
[[1,1],
 [2,0]]
```

Comment: What to output for a (x,y) case that has no `z` left after masking out?

Comment: Some distinguisher such as -1 would work- as long as it is noted that is missing data and I can plot accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `[[1,1],[2,1]]` instead for Edit 2?

Comment: No- I am looking for the lowest point in z -not the lowest value- sorry for the confusion. the output is correct, I will work on clarifying the question more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input array, you could do -

```
np.where((A < thresh).all(0),-1,(A >= thresh).argmax(0))
```

**Sample runs**

Run #1:

```
In [87]: A
Out[87]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 5]],

       [[3, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[2, 1],
        [4, 9]]])

In [88]: thresh = 3

In [89]: np.where((A < thresh).all(0),-1,(A >= thresh).argmax(0))
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 0]])
```

Run #2:

```
In [82]: A
Out[82]: 
array([[[17,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 5, 13, 11,  2],
        [ 9, 16, 11, 19],
        [11, 16,  6,  3],
        [15,  9, 14, 14]],

       [[18, 19,  5,  8],
        [13, 13, 17,  2],
        [17, 12, 16,  0],
        [19, 14, 12,  5],
        [ 7,  8,  4,  7]],

       [[10, 12, 11,  2],
        [10, 18,  6, 15],
        [ 4, 16,  0, 16],
        [16, 18,  2,  1],
        [10, 19,  9,  4]]])

In [83]: thresh = 10

In [84]: np.where((A < thresh).all(0),-1,(A >= thresh).argmax(0))
Out[84]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  2,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: This works well along with the answer below- however, I am trying to find z indices, not z values. Is there a more efficient way of doing that without doing np.unravel_index to each one individually? I'll edit my question to clarify, sorry

Comment: @Laxsnor Use `.argmin` then in place of `.min`?

Comment: Actually- just tested it- I'm not looking for the unmasked minimum, I am looking for the lowest point where it is not masked. Sorry for the confusion- see my edit above. In your example, the first row of output would instead be: [16,11,19,18].

Comment: The edited answer still has the same problem as before- it is retrieving the minimum non-masked point instead of the lowest non-masked point. I have further clarified my expected in/out in my question. Your answer first row should be (taking 0 to be the "lowest"): [1,2,0,0] or (taking 2 to be the lowest): [2,2,2,1]. I should have made a better distinction between lowest and minimum- I mean the one that has the smallest z coordinate.

Comment: The newest edit looks like it works perfectly, thank you very much! I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @Laxsnor Glad to help! Yeah that "lowest" part got me confused initially. Well all's good now :)